# Web Scrape an Image with rvest R

Tags: html, r, image, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having a problem when trying to scrape an image from [this page](https://covid-19vis.cmm.uchile.cl/chart). My code is as follow:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://covid-19vis.cmm.uchile.cl/chart")

m <- '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]'

grafico_cmm <- html_node(url, xpath = m) %>% html_attr('src')
```

When I run the above code, the result is NA. Does someone know how can I scrape the plot or maybe the data from the page?

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: It not an image, it is an interactive chart. For an image, you would need to scrape the datapoints and re-create as a chart and then convert to an image. Xpath is also invalid. The data comes from an API call `https://covid-19vis.cmm.uchile.cl/api/data?scope=0&indicatorId=57`

Comment: Thanks @QHarr I did that and seems to had worked although the content isn't the data of the chart. Do you know how to extract it?

Comment: Check the network traffic for the other API calls. There were several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not an image, it is an interactive chart. For an image, you would need to scrape the data points and re-create as a chart and then convert to an image. Xpath is also invalid.
The data comes from an API call. I checked the values against the chart and this is the correct endpoint.

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://covid-19vis.cmm.uchile.cl/api/data?scope=0&indicatorId=57', simplifyVector = T)
```

The chart needs some tidying but here is a basic plot of the r values:

```
data$date <- data$date %>% as.Date()

library("ggplot2")

ggplot(data=data,
       aes(x=date, y=value, colour ='red')) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "R Efectivo", labels = c("Chile"))

print tail(data)
```